# How to Export Large data into Excel

Tags: r, excel

I am using `sink()` function for printing R output to excel/text file. my program output is too large. I found at the end of Excel/text output file a message

```
[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 5326 rows ]
```

Also I have more than one large outputs to print. I also want them on separate (different)  sheets of one excel file .

Actually, the output comes in matrix form, as the value of loop increases, the rows and columns of square matrices also increases. the function `append` does not work due to difference of rows and columns number. to avoid this error I used `if` condition and deal separately using `rbind` for similar matrices. But there is more than 5 thousand iteration through double loop (and the method also repeats), so it is impossible to write 1000's of `if` and `rbind` conditions and save them into separate sheets and files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you don't want a `csv` you can use package `xlsx` and it is pretty easy to save multiple sheets e.g.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=1:100)   # make data
df2 <- data.frame(x=1:1000, y=1:1000) 

library(xlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()         # create blank workbook
sheet1 <- createSheet(wb, sheetName="mysheet1") # create different sheets
sheet2 <- createSheet(wb, sheetName="mysheet2")
addDataFrame(df1, sheet1)  # add data to the sheets
addDataFrame(df2, sheet2)
saveWorkbook(wb, "mysheets.xlsx")  # write the file with multiple sheets
```

Comment: Actually, the output comes in matrix form, as the value of loop increases, the rows and columns of square matrices also increases. the function `append` does not work due to difference of rows and columns number. to avoid this error I used `if` condition and deal separately using `rbind` for similar matrices. But there is more than 5 thousand iteration through double loop (and the method also repeats), so it is impossible to write 1000's of `if` and `rbind` conditions and save them into separate sheets and files.

Comment: As the other poster states, your comment does not make sense, there is no context.

Comment: please send me ur email, so that i send you the whole output which makes you understand.

Answer (score 5):

You can write your data frame to a csv file and then open it in excel using `write.csv` (Read its documentation using `?write.csv`):

```
## To write a CSV file for input to Excel one might use
x <- data.frame(a = I("a \" quote"), b = pi)
write.table(x, file = "foo.csv", sep = ",", col.names = NA,
            qmethod = "double")
```

Comment: I have more than one different outputs from a program, can i save them  into different sheets. Also my data is generated through double loop.

Comment: This exports a csv file which you import in excel, when importing you can ask excel to add it as a new sheet. Just export each data frame into a new file

Comment: But through this, I got only the last values generated through loop.

Comment: inside the loop write the values to a different files, you will end up with multiple files

Comment: Actually, the output comes in matrix form, as the value of loop increases, the rows and columns of square matrices also increases. the function `append` does not work due to difference of rows and columns number. to avoid this error I used `if` condition and deal separately using `rbind` for similar matrices. But there is more than 5 thousand iteration through double loop (and the method also repeats), so it is impossible to write 1000's of `if` and `rbind` conditions and save them into separate sheets and files.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, when you build your matrix, when do you want to save to csv ?

Comment: I have sent you my problem on your Facebook account by Using Facebook Massage Service. Please review it.